# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git when git add

Tags: git, github, repository

I had some troble with my repo as I started getting `fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/master (Conflicted copy of AO722 2013-03-26)`

As I couldn't find how to solve it, I downloaded my latest copy from the repo as a zip and replaced the folder.

I thought that I had keeped `.git` files in my project folder,but now I'm getting this error:

```
$ git add .
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What can I do to get my project working again? As you can see I'm a rookie in git issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to save the code that I had changed in another file, then delete the proyect and do this:

```
git clone git@github.com:user/my-project.git subFolder
```